# Number to String conversion always invariant (i.e. without culture) in Dart?

Tags: dart

In Dart, when converting a number to a string (without a special package):

```dart
double d = 123.456;
String s = "$d";
```

or, when parsing a string to a number (without a special package):

```dart
double d2 = double.parse("12.99");
```

**Is it guaranteed that the conversions are culture-invariant, meaning that it does not matter what culture the user or the app is using?**

I am asking because I need this information for input and output that a user never sees but the computer needs to read and write (so it should be culture-independent).

And I am asking because I am coming from the .NET world where the current culture *will* affect string<->number conversions automatically and you have to explicitly opt-out to get culture invariant behavior.

I believe that the Dart world behaves the other way around: It's culture-invariant by default, and you have to opt-in to get culture-dependent behavior.

But I have never seen "evidence" for my believe.

**Update**

To clarify, with "independent of culture", I mean for example that as decimals separator always `.` is used and never `,`.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by dependent on "culture"? Do you mean like using `,` vs `.` for separating decimals? The `parse` and `toString` methods included with Dart always use the same format.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore: yes I mean things like the decimal separator `,` vs `.` .   When you say "they always use the same format", is there any official documentation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `double.parse()` or `double.tryParse()` from the core library, i.e. not using e.g. the `intl` package, the decimal point is, and is only, a period (`.`) sign.

Information in the official docs:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/double/parse.html

Comment: Wow! The documentation to `double.parse()` really explicitly states _"decimal point (.)"_. I only read the documentation for [`double.toString()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/double/toString.html) which does not explicitly state something. However, it indirectly gives some information: _"For all doubles, d, converting to a string and parsing the string back gives the same value again: d == double.parse(d.toString())"_. So, together with the explicit information for `parse`, this indirectly also tells us that `toString` also always uses `.` as decimal separator.

Comment: So, puzzle solved, I think :-)

Comment: Sorry I missed your first part about converting double to String. You are however correct in your assumption.